# Sencha Touch 2 native android Facebook SDK redirect_url

Tags: facebook, extjs, sdk

is there a way to get the Facebook SDK with a native android build with Sencha Touch 2 to work?
It runs find on my browser but when I wanna try it as native android app, I get the message "Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application."

It makes sense. I added "localhost" as redirect_uri. Prolly the phone doesn't use localhost for it. How can i fix that? :)

Thanks